# Best practices for using CSS classes as a state machine?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css

I'm working on a CSS3/Javascript UI that is written essentially as a state machine, and the transitions between states (animations) are done entirely in CSS3 animations and transitions.

Right now, to trigger a state change I'm doing something like the following:

```
function changeState(oldState, newState) {
     element.classList.remove(getCSSClassName(oldState));
     element.classList.add(getCSSClassName(newState));
}
```

This seems fine for now, and everything seems to work in webkit-based browsers. The rendering of the element doesn't get updated until both of these commands are run (probably nothing until the javascript execution ends). However, I know that some browsers (firefox in particular) layout/rendering changes can occur in the middle of javascript execution.

Is this how I should be doing this? Or is there a better way to trigger a "state change" in terms of swapping CSS classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.className` and prepare the correct string before you assign it:

```
function changeState(oldState, newState) {
     var str = element.className;
     str = str.replace(getCSSClassName(oldState),"");
     str = str + getCSSClassName(newState);
     element.className = str;
}
```

This will make sure that the assignment is done without interrupt. Note that `classList` isn't supported by IE≤9.

Comment: Why don't you directly do something like `element.className = str.replace(getCSSClassName(oldState),getCSSClassName(newState));`. This way, no need for `""` and any sort of addition.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Animator {
  constructor(strClass) {
    this.slide = document.querySelector(strClass)
    this.slideOriginClass = this.slide.className;
  }
  set(num) {
    this.slide.className = this.slideOriginClass + ' state-' + num
  }
  get() {
    console.log(this.slide.classList.length);
  }
};

var animator = new Animator('.slide');
animator.set(4)
setTimeouta( ()=> { animator.set(1) , 1000 }
```